# Getting data attribute from class with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a number of divs with the same `season-list` class and each has a `data-episode-count` data attribute. I need to be able to grab the attribute on click and use that value to hide `js-show-more-trigger` if the value of the attribute is greater than 6. I'm currently looping through all `season-list` classes, but not sure how to grab the data attribute from the div:

**HTML**

```
<div class="js-season-list-item" id="season-5" style="display: block;">
  <div class="season-list" data-episode-count="3">
    <div class="season-list__item">
      <div class="episode-item">
        <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
          <div class="episode-card__overlay"><a href="/play/3099013"><span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099013"><svg class="svg svg-play"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use></svg></span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="episode-details">
          <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 1</h1>
          <p></p>
          <p class="runtime">21min</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="season-list__item">
      <div class="episode-item">
        <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
          <div class="episode-card__overlay"><a href="/play/3099014"><span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099014"><svg class="svg svg-play"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use></svg></span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="episode-details">
          <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 2</h1>
          <p></p>
          <p class="runtime">21min</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="season-list__item">
      <div class="episode-item">
        <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
          <div class="episode-card__overlay"><a href="/play/3099015"><span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099015"><svg class="svg svg-play"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use></svg></span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="episode-details">
          <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 3</h1>
          <p></p>
          <p class="runtime">21min</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
let trigger = document.getElementsByClassName('js-show-more-trigger');
let seasonList = document.getElementsByClassName("season-list")
for(let i = 0; i < seasonList.length; i++) {
  if(seasonList[i].getAttribute('data-episode-count') < 6){
    trigger.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Codepen: [Link](https://codepen.io/testermytesty/pen/xWdgzX?editors=1010)

Comment: `seasonList[i].dataset.episodeCount`

Comment: `console.log(seasonList[i].getAttribute('data-episode-count'))`

Comment: Four identical answers within a few minutes... hmm.

Comment: Everyone is chomping at the bit, haha.

Answer (score 1):

You can get data in Javascript by dataset property. In your case:

```
let seasonList = document.getElementsByClassName("season-list")
for(let i = 0; i < seasonList.length; i++) {
  console.log(seasonList[i].dataset.episodeCount)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

```
seasonList[i].getAttribute('data-episode-count');
```

With [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

```
seasonList[i].dataset.episodeCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost you can check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) for better understating.

If I understand you correctly, you want to **hide** the "Show More" link when the `episodeCount > 6`, the snippet below is working as intended. Your `if`statement was only hiding the `trigger` if the value was less then 6.

You can check the behavior by changing the `data-episode-count` value.

```js
let trigger = document.getElementsByClassName('js-show-more-trigger');
let seasonList = document.getElementsByClassName("season-list")
for(let i = 0; i < seasonList.length; i++) {
  if(seasonList[i].dataset.episodeCount > 6){
    trigger[i].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.season-list{
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="js-season-list-item" id="season-5" style="display: block;">
  <div class="season-list" data-episode-count="7">
    <div class="season-list__item">
      <div class="episode-item">
        <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
          <div class="episode-card__overlay"><a href="/play/3099013"><span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099013"><svg class="svg svg-play"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use></svg></span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="episode-details">
          <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 1</h1>
          <p></p>
          <p class="runtime">21min</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="season-list__item">
      <div class="episode-item">
        <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
          <div class="episode-card__overlay"><a href="/play/3099014"><span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099014"><svg class="svg svg-play"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use></svg></span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="episode-details">
          <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 2</h1>
          <p></p>
          <p class="runtime">21min</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="season-list__item">
      <div class="episode-item">
        <div class="episode-card js-episode-card">
          <div class="episode-card__overlay"><a href="/play/3099015"><span class="play-circle sm" data-play-path="/play/3099015"><svg class="svg svg-play"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/svg/svg-defs.svg#svg-play">svg-play</use></svg></span></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="episode-details">
          <h1 class="heading md hvy">Episode 3</h1>
          <p></p>
          <p class="runtime">21min</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="show-more"><span class="js-show-more-trigger">Show 
More</span></div>
```

Comment: This is a good start and gets all the available `data-episode-count`, but how would I target one specifically if there are multiple `season-list` divs on the page?